# Windows 7/ 12.04 Dual Boot Mess

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, wubi

I am new to Ubuntu and to Linux in general.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 to a brand new desktop which had Windows 7 pre-installed, and am dual-booting between them.

Both operating systems work well.

Then I tried to change the order of the boot menu to make Ubuntu first and Windows 7 second. I did this from the windows side (it seems that my setup is relying on the Windows boot loader, which I don't think I need to change) using the built-in startup manager (I think that's what windows calls it- it's in the control panel).

I set Ubuntu as first (default if no user input).

Then I *accidentally* ("hmmm...I wonder what this button does?") set the menu timeout to `0`.

Now, I cannot change the menu timeout (because I cannot get into Windows) and without doing so, I cannot select Windows as the OS I would like to boot (I cannot get into windows).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The information you've provided indicates that you have installed Ubuntu inside Windows with Wubi. Therefore, the boot loader whose menu you're not seeing is the Windows boot loader, and *not* GRUB (Ubuntu's boot loader).

You should be able to get the Windows boot menu to appear by pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> while booting.

(If you had a similar problem, where you set *Ubuntu's* boot loader timeout to `0`, then you would instead hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting.)

Comment: Tried that already (f8), no affect whatsoever...